# pivot_wider outputs <S3: vctrs_list_of> objects

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following data set that I am trying to spread.

```
    #create df    
df <- structure(list(file_number = c("3098129", "3096451", "3096774", 
"3095276", "3095464", "3096846", "3097132", "3096355", "3096951", 
"3096328", "3095441", "3096325", "3094412", "3096366", "3096372", 
"3096507", "3098510", "3096335", "3096403", "3094343", "3096941", 
"3096419", "3094431", "3096495", "3094647", "3094487", "3094947", 
"3094398", "3094386", "3094367", "3097480", "3096425", "3095193", 
"3095839a", "3097197", "3098453", "3098549", "3098428", "3096427", 
"3096895", "3096434", "3094835", "3096312", "3094517", "3094372", 
"3096387", "3096480", "3098504", "3096338", "3094615", "3096382", 
"3096638", "3096750", "3096418", "3094734", "3098503", "3096311", 
"3097197", "3094353", "3098442", "3097111", "3097325", "3096531", 
"3096405", "3096301", "3096692", "3096495", "3098406", "3098422", 
"3096315", "3096951", "3094491", "3096304", "3098416", "3096332", 
"3098404", "3098419", "3095225", "3094404", "3096374", "3098411", 
"3098556", "3096398", "3094421b", "3098477", "3094369b", "3098463", 
"3096893", "3098514", "3098477", "3098465", "3094560", "3098409", 
"3096434", "3097557", "3095061", "3098419", "3096404", "3095441", 
"3096537", "3098503", "3098400", "3097808", "3096389b", "3098446", 
"3096330", "3095533", "3094421a", "3094339", "3095578", "3094404", 
"3098552", "3098514", "3096630", "3096941", "3097027", "3096322", 
"3096514", "3098484", "3097038", "3096672", "3098483", "3094373", 
"3096774", "3096677", "3096408", "3096664", "3096365", "3096491", 
"3096820", "3096514", "3096556", "3096292", "3096495", "3094781", 
"3094344", "3094487", "3094690", "3098504", "3096503"), reader = c("aa", 
"aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", 
"aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ae", "ae", "ae", 
"ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", 
"ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "ae", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", 
"db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", "db", 
"db", "db", "db", "db", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", 
"dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", "dl", 
"dl", "dl", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", 
"mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", "mk", 
"mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", 
"mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "mm", "np", "np", 
"np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", 
"np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np", "np"), event = c("fail", 
"fail", "fail", "fail", "pass", "fail", "fail", "pass", "fail", 
"fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", 
"fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "fail", 
"fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "fail", 
"pass", "fail", "fail", "pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "pass", 
"fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", 
"pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", 
"fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", 
"pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", "pass", "fail", 
"pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", 
"fail", "pass", "fail", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", "fail", 
"fail", "pass", "fail", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", "pass", 
"pass", "fail", "pass", "pass", "fail", "fail", "pass", "pass", 
"fail", "fail", "fail")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -140L))

>head(df)
file_number reader  event
3098129     aa      fail        
3096451     aa      fail        
3096774     aa      fail        
3095276     aa      fail
```

But when I run the following `tidyr::pivot_wider` I get the output `<S3: vctrs_list_of>`. I think this has to do with having multiple values of the same type in the `names_from` column.

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = file_number, names_from = reader, values_from = event)

id                       aa                 ae
3098129         <S3: vctrs_list_of> <S3: vctrs_list_of>     
3096451         <S3: vctrs_list_of> <S3: vctrs_list_of>
```

Along with the following warning:

```
Values in `event` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(event = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(event = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(event = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
```

My question is: **Why does pivot_wider output S3 vector lists?**

EDIT 
-added better reproducible example. 
-redefined question.

Comment: The behavior you used is not reproducible

Comment: working on a more reproducible example

Comment: I think I understand why it is happening on your original dataset.  Please check my updated post

Comment: I think this would work, but I have some cases with missing values. Without the unique id variables "id" it looks as though it is collapsing several ids together. Almost done de-identifying a better example.

Comment: not following your description about missing values.  if you have missing values, filter the NA rows out, then create the sequence by group

Comment: When the table is pivoted there should be missing values for some of the readers.

Comment: Yes, that would be automatically provided if the combination is not found and if there is a sequence column

Comment: I did not state my final goals clearly. I did want the data collapsed by ```file_number``` and to create ```NA``` for those missing combinations.  I believe using the ```tidyr::unnest()``` gets me there without creating a unique row id

Comment: Since I was able to answer my questions with the ```unnest```. I will leave this questions as the "why does this occur". It will probably be more useful this way since the pivot_wider is such a new package.

Comment: Okay, whatever you wish. and I don't see a question there if this is the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if we have the `names_from` column without a sequence identifier for duplicate rows, this can happen

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%        
    pivot_wider(names_from = reader, values_from = event)
# A tibble: 124 x 8
#   file_number          aa          ae          db          dl          mk          mm          np
#   <chr>       <list<chr>> <list<chr>> <list<chr>> <list<chr>> <list<chr>> <list<chr>> <list<chr>>
# 1 3098129             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 2 3096451             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 3 3096774             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [1]
# 4 3095276             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 5 3095464             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 6 3096846             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 7 3097132             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 8 3096355             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# 9 3096951             [1]         [0]         [0]         [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]
#10 3096328             [1]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]         [0]
# … with 114 more rows
```

So, for those cases, we need to create the sequence by the grouping variable

```
df %>%        
    group_by(reader) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% # recreated unique identifier column
    pivot_wider(names_from = reader, values_from = event)
# A tibble: 139 x 9
#   file_number    rn aa    ae    db    dl    mk    mm    np   
#   <chr>       <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 3098129         1 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 2 3096451         2 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 3 3096774         3 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 4 3095276         4 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 5 3095464         5 pass  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 6 3096846         6 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 7 3097132         7 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 8 3096355         8 pass  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# 9 3096951         9 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#10 3096328        10 fail  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
# … with 129 more rows
```

---

The columns are all `factors` because in the `data.frame` call, if we don't. specify the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, by default it would be `TRUE`

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ id    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# $ reader: Factor w/ 2 levels "aa","bb": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
# $ event : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Instead,  specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and columns will be `character`

```
df <- data.frame(id = as.character(rep(seq(1:5),2)), 
             reader = c("aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb"), 
             event = as.character(rbinom(10, size = 1, prob=0.5)),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
             )
```

Answer (score 8):

I am able to fix the issue by using the `tidyr::unnest` function on the S3 vector objects.

```
df %>% ungroup() %>% pivot_wider(names_from = reader, values_from = event) %>% tidyr::unnest()
id  aa  bb
1   0   0       
2   0   1       
3   1   0       
4   1   1       
5   0   1
```

NOTE: all variables are factors now

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

If you will end up with values that can't compose a vector, you will get a list instead.

This will happen for instance if `pivot_wider` finds and combines multiple values into a list because it couldn't uniquely identify a record, or because the values are not all of the same basic type, or because any value is not a basic type or can't properly compose a vector such as `NULL`.

**More details:**

In your example, you have a duplicate record:

```
df %>%
  filter(duplicated(.))    

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# file_number reader event
# <chr>       <chr>  <chr>
# 1 3098477     mk     fail
```

Because there are multiple `event` for the same `file_number` + `reader`, `pivot_wider` doesn't know what to do with it other than combining them in a list, and the `event` column is now to a list of lists with these values combined, as warned with `` Values in `event` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols. ``:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = reader, values_from = event) %>%
  filter(file_number == "3098477") %>%
  select(mk) %>%
  glimpse

# Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
# * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
# * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
# * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
# Rows: 1
# Columns: 1
# $ mk <list> <"fail", "fail">
```

If this is was mistake, or if you don't really care about duplicates records you can:

```
df %>%
  unique %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = reader, values_from = event)

# # A tibble: 124 x 8
# file_number aa    ae    db    dl    mk    mm    np
# <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 3098129     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2 3096451     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3 3096774     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    fail
# 4 3095276     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5 3095464     pass  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6 3096846     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7 3097132     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 8 3096355     pass  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 9 3096951     fail  NA    NA    pass  NA    NA    NA
# 10 3096328     fail  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# # … with 114 more rows
```

Alternatively, if you do expect duplicates or even multiple distinct values for the same  `file_number` + `reader`, you can teach `pivot_wider` how to combine these values with a function:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = file_number, names_from = reader, values_from = event, values_fn = function(values) paste(values, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  filter(file_number == "3098477")

# # A tibble: 1 x 8
# file_number aa    ae    db    dl    mk         mm    np
# <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>
# 1 3098477     NA    NA    NA    NA    fail, fail NA    NA
```

Finally, if you want to keep multiple rows with an entry for each `value` per `file_number` + `reader`, adding another column with an artificial unique identifier will do the trick.